# WIX - Conditions For Actions/Components depending on First Install or Upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

i am relatively new to Wix. I created a Setup where we can define a connection string on the first install. Now i wanted to upgrade, and have the possibility to skip some Dialogs that are only used in the first install (like the one that asks for the server and database), and i didn't want to remove some XML files that were configured in the first install.
For what i have read, a major upgrade removes the previous installation, and replaces all the files.
How can i get a condition that says if its first isntall or upgrade, to just install some components, skip some dialogs, not reconfigure XML Files (i'm using util:XmlFile) and not remove some files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could condition the Components and Actions using the Installed property and UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE property.

Comment: The condition `<Condition>REMOVE=ALL AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Condition>` in a component tag is true on an upgrade, using the <MajorUpgrade ... > tag. Makes no sense to me. How can that be?